# Support required in regex writting in PCRE

Tags: regex

I am not very good in regex and learning this on daily basis. I got issue where I want to extract data after `@` and before `>` if it exist in the field value else it should return as its    data.

Data example: `<abc@xyz.com>, chene.com abc.xyz@xyz.com`

Expected output of my regex should be `xyz.com`, `chene.com` and `xyz.com`.

What I wrote is

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})
```

but this is not fetching all of the required data.

Comment: Try `(?:[\w.-]+@)?[\w.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zVaOPP/1).

Comment: Thanks but this the above full match is <abc@xyz.com> and chene.com where I want anything after @ but before > and if that doe not exist then return what is present example chene.com

Comment: Then, doesn't your [original regex work for you](https://regex101.com/r/zVaOPP/3)?

Comment: No If am writting this like (?<from_domain>([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}))>  then I am getting output of from_domain as xyz.com but it is not matching with chene.com

Comment: Then remove `>`, why add it? `([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})` *does* fetch you the required data.

Comment: Thanks, This will work but if data is abc.xyz@xyz.com then its matching with abc.xyz data too and giving me output as abc.xyz@xyz.com how I can negate this condition?

Comment: I  solved this issue after using (<.*@)?(?<from_domain>(\w+\.\w+))

Comment: Not sure it works, see https://regex101.com/r/zVaOPP/4. I think you need `(?:<?[\w.-]+@)?(?<from_domain>[\w.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5})`, see https://regex101.com/r/zVaOPP/5

Answer (score 0):

I suggest *capturing* the part you need using

```
(?:<?[\w.-]+@)?\b(?<from_domain>\w[\w.-]*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5})\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zVaOPP/6)

**Details**

- `(?:<?[\w.-]+@)?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches

  - `<?` - an optional `<` char
  - `[\w.-]+` - 1+ word chars, `.` or `-` chars
  - `@` -  a `@` char
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<from_domain>\w[\w.-]*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5})` - Group "from_domain":

  - `\w[\w.-]*` - a word char followed with 0 or more word, dot or hyphen chars
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `[a-zA-Z]{2,5}` - two to five ASCII letters
- `\b` - a word boundary